# StartupinfoEX and console redirection

Tags: c++, console, handle, createprocess

i want to create a child process with handle inheritance to false AND with console redirection.
for this i create the stdinput namepipe handle and set the inheritance to true for this handle and add it in the structure StartupinfoEX that i send after to the createprocess

the probleme is that, the child process receive correctly the handle (i check it in the process explorer) but the console redirection is not assigned (it's look like the previous handle is not assigned to the stdinput) !

when of course i use a standart STARTUPINFO with inheritance to true in createprocess everything work great ...

my code

FServerPipe := CreateNamedPipe(....);

.........

```
  si.StartupInfo.hStdInput  := FServerPipe;
  si.StartupInfo.hStdOutput := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  si.StartupInfo.hStdError  := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

.........

UpdateProcThreadAttribute(...)

.........

```
  CheckError(Not CreateProcess(
                               PChar(aPhpInterpreterFilename),   // pointer to name of executable module
                               nil,                              // pointer to command line string
                               nil,                              // pointer to process security attributes
                               NiL,                              // pointer to thread security attributes
                               TrUE,                             // handle inheritance flag
                               CREATE_NO_WINDOW
                               or
                               EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,           // creation flags
                               Pchar(aEnvironment),              // pointer to new environment block
                               nil,                              // pointer to current directory name
                               TStartupInfo(PStartupInfo(@si)^),                   // pointer to STARTUPINFO
                               fServerProcessInformation         // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
                              ));
```

any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: This is only a small part of the subset of your code which could be considered as pertinent to your question. For example, where is the code which sets the lpAttributeList member of STARTUPINFOEX ?

Comment: On handle inheritance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/16/10248328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try posting a minimal compilable & runnable example - most of the setup code is missing in your snippet, and handle redirection setup with pipes is a bit finicky to get working... you need to set security attributes, handle duplication, endpoint closing et cetera.

In case you haven't seen it, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351) MSDN article shows redirection with C code.